# How to add fuzziness to search query in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to implement fuzziness on a particular field in a cross-fields query. It's a bit difficult though.

So the query should:

1. Match phrases across fields.
2. Match an exact match against partNumber and barcode (no fuzziness)
3. Match fuzzy terms against title and subtitle.

The query that I have so far is below - note the fuzziness isn't working at all in query so far.

So this should match 1 result which is "Amazing t-Shirt" in the title, and Blue in the subtitle. (note the spelling error).

Is it possible to implement the fuzziness at the index mapping level instead? Title and subtitle are quite short in the data set - maybe 30 - 40 characters combined maximum.

Otherwise how can I add fuzziness to the title and subtitle in the query?

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
        "query": "Bleu Amazing T-Shirt",
        "fuzziness": "auto",
        "operator": "and",
        "fields": [
          "identity.partNumber^4",
          "identity.altIdentifier^4",
          "identity.barcode",
          "identity.mpn",
          "identity.ppn",
          "descriptions.title",
          "descriptions.subtitle"
        ],
        "type": "cross_fields"
      }
  },
  "fields": [
    "identity.partNumber",
    "identity.barcode",
    "identity.ppn",
    "descriptions.title",
    "descriptions.subtitle"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

well it doesn't seem to be supported to fuzzy search using cross_fields, there was a few related issues. So instead of crossfield search, I copied the title & subtitle to a new field at index time and split the query like below. Seems to work for my test cases at least....

```
"query": {
      "bool": {
        "should": [
          {
            "multi_match": {
              "query": "{{searchTerm}}",
              "operator": "and",
              "fields": [
                "identity.partNumber^4",
                "identity.altIdentifier^4",
                "identity.barcode",
                "identity.mpn",
                "identity.ppn"
              ],
              "type": "best_fields"
            }
          },
          {
            "match": {
              "fuzzyFields": {
                "query": "{{searchTerm}}",
                "operator": "and",
                "fuzziness": "auto"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```